# Binding GridViewComboBoxColumn to a datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I already know how to specify the datasource but afther doing that it is not populated yet so i was thinking you need some kind of bind() command to populate the comboboxcolumn in the edit form
This below is how i bind the datasource to the comboboxcolumn (and yes i am sure that ds has data rows in it)

```
(ASPxGridView4.Columns["Naam"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn).PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = ds as DataSet;
```

So could anyone tell me how i can now populate the comboboxcolumn in edit mode?

**Edit**

```
protected void ASPxGridView4_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInitNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            ds = Session["ds"] as DataSet;
        }
        GridViewDataComboBoxColumn column = (ASPxGridView4.Columns["Naam"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn);
        column.PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        column.PropertiesComboBox.ValueField = "Naam";
        column.PropertiesComboBox.ValueType = typeof(string);
        column.PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "Naam";
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code which should work:

```
DataSet dataSet = ds as DataSet;
GridViewDataComboBoxColumn column = (ASPxGridView4.Columns["Naam"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn);
column.PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
column.PropertiesComboBox.ValueField = "SomeValueField";
column.PropertiesComboBox.ValueType = typeof(int);  // type of the SomeValueField
column.PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "SomeTextField";
```

Also, please refer to the [GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Class](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataComboBoxColumntopic) topic.

**UPDATE** Your code should be implemented in the [CellEditorInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CellEditorInitializetopic) event as shown below:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e) {
        if(e.Editor is ASPxComboBox) {
            ASPxComboBox combo = ((ASPxComboBox)e.Editor);
            combo.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            combo.TextField = "Naam";
            combo.ValueField = "Naam";
            combo.DataBindItems();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not seem to work either i will edit my question with some extra code how it is now