# Binding GridViewComboBoxColumn to a datasource at Page_Load

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a grid with a GridViewComboBoxColumn column.  I have a datasource that is a list of objects.  I need to assign the data in Page_Load.  This does not work:

```
protected void Page_Load() {
    GridViewDataComboBoxColumn gridColumn = Grid.Columns["NumericData"]
        as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn;

    gridColumn.PropertiedropsComboBox.DataSource = DataSourceMadeUpOfAList;
    gridColumn.PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "SpelledOutNumbers";
    gridColumn.PropertiesComboBox.ValueField = "ActualNumbers";
...
```

I have looked here: [Binding GridViewComboBoxColumn to a datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898136/binding-gridviewcomboboxcolumn-to-a-datasource)

And that does work, but only in the edit form.  I have my filter row enabled and those drop downs need to be populated as well.  The aforementioned solution does not work with the filters (for obvious reasons).  Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine here.  Please make certain, that the type of the ValueField and the type of the column to which the ComboBoxColumn is bound(column.FieldName) is the same.  Finally, here is my example:

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" Width="100%"  ClientInstanceName="grid"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" KeyFieldName="ProductID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
            <ClearFilterButton Visible="True">
            </ClearFilterButton>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProductName" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SupplierID" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="CategoryID" VisibleIndex="3">
            <PropertiesComboBox ValueType="System.String">
            </PropertiesComboBox>
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Products]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        GridViewDataComboBoxColumn col = ASPxGridView1.Columns["CategoryID"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn;
        col.PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = GetDataSource();
        col.PropertiesComboBox.ValueField = "Id";
        col.PropertiesComboBox.TextField = "Text";
    }

...


public class Record {
    public Record(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = "Row " + id.ToString();
    }

    private int id;
    public int Id {
        get { return id; }
        set {
            id = value;
        }
    }
    private string text;
    public string Text {
        get { return text; }
    }
```

Comment: I have duplicated this solution within my current project and it does not work. As I walk through the Page_Load and step past the TextField setting, I watched the data, and the Count for Items is 0. The data is in the DataSource of the grid column, but it does not appear as though the data is actually binded to the column.  The only real difference, other than the project, is that I have no DataSourceID in my grid as my data is provided in the code behind.

Comment: Also, if the ValueType is to match the ValueField, why is ValueType set to String when Id is an int?

Comment: Since your data is provided in runtime, make certain that you bind the grid to data in the Page_Init event as it is explained in the http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18183.aspx article

Comment: I did bind my data in the Init, but not at the right time.  Got it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it work as drop down filter on header ? Or it displays drop down on each row ?